# Is there an easy way to view the print queue?

Tags: printing, indicator

With the (apparent) loss of the print indicator in Natty, I'm having a little trouble keeping track of my print queue easily.

At the moment to bring up a print queue, I bring up the "Printing" application using the Dash, then go to the Printer -> View Print Queue menu. This seems a little convoluted to me, and I'd like an easier way.

Is there some way to go directly to the printer queue in Natty, like you used to be able to do by clicking on the printer indicator in earlier Ubuntu versions? Alternatively, can we turn the printer indicator icon back on when there are (or have recently been) queued print jobs?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/q/781887/451919

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/771562).

The old printer applet should be whitelisted and an actual print indicator should be written for 11.10.

Answer (score 30):

system-config-printer works.

1. Press the Ubuntu logo on the launcher bar, type `printers`, open the `Printers` app.
2. While in the `Printers` app, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.
3. A list of jobs will appear. From this list one can manage jobs, delete them, etc.

Answer (score 18):

**`lpstat -R`**

from the [pre-installed](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64.manifest) [cups-client](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/cups-client/filelist) package.

Sample output with 2 jobs:

```
0 XP-202-203-206-Series-27 ciro              1024 Wed 22 Apr 2015 12:44:38 PM CEST
1 XP-202-203-206-Series-28 ciro              1024 Wed 22 Apr 2015 12:49:08 PM CEST
```

Jobs disappear once done.

Other possibilities:

- visit http://localhost:631/jobs/
- `lpq -a` from `cups-bsd` as mentioned at: [Cancelling print jobs and dealing with printer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/295464/cancelling-print-jobs-and-dealing-with-printer)

Also check out this great tutorial: https://web.archive.org/web/20150912145157/http://www.eecs.utk.edu/resources/it/kb/printing/linux-command-line/

CLI is always the more stable way :-)

Comment: the tutorial link is broken (404). The content is still available on web archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20150912145157/http://www.eecs.utk.edu/resources/it/kb/printing/linux-command-line/

Comment: Add also `-t` switch to show all the details: `lpstat -Rt`