# Cancelling print jobs and dealing with printer

Tags: 13.04, printing, hp, plasma

Where can I see printing jobs in queue? Sometimes even after restarting the computer, a print is not forgotten and when I turn on printer it begins to print some jobs from previous actions which I no longer need them be printed.

How can I see the printing jobs queue and cancel them?!

I use Ubuntu 13.04 with Plasma Desktop. No messages is shown when a print job is waiting to be printed. Also there's not any message if a paper jam occurs or any other printer messages.

Comment: my printer model: hp laserjet p1102

Comment: For listing jobs see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/37247/is-there-an-easy-way-to-view-the-print-queue/612409#612409

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open a terminal and type "lpq -a" This will print all available printer queues. Read the man page of "cancel" to see how to remove print jobs from a specific queue.

As far as printer management is concerned, each vendor usually provides vendor specific software for that job.For example, HP printers are managed with hplip. Check the manufacturer support website for linux specific software. If they don't provide any let them know how disappointed you are with their policy not providing such support.

Answer (score 9):

run `lprm` without parameters to remove the last job http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/cancel.1.html